# what is "Hot new stuff" exactly?

Tags: package-management, updates, security

I have, perhaps only a problem with how it sounds, "Get Hot New Stuff" doesn't Sound like a security update, what is this non-sense anyhow?

[image]

Comment: Click on "Technical description" and find out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual package name is `libknewstuff2-4`. It is actually a library for KDE that enables data sharing capabilities to various KDE applications.

From `apt-cache show libknewstuff2-4`:

> The KNewStuff2 ("Get Hot New Stuff" v2)  library adds data sharing 
>   capabilities to KDE Applications. Technically, it implements the GHNS
>   and DXS  specifications. The library consists of three parts: the data
>   management core  and GHNS protocol implementation, the DXS web service
>   handler, and the user  interface classes like dialogs and buttons.

Also there is a version 3, packaged as `libknewstuff3-4`.